# Can I set a preferred Audio Device in Exoplayer or MediaPlayer for video playback?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

For the most part it seems this is handled using system default device.

Is there a way, like in `AudioTrack.setPreferredDevice(AudioDeviceInfo info)` in `ExoPlayer`/ `MediaPlayer` to manually set the output device for a video?

If not are there any alternatives available that will allow me to do so?

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Can you please explain more what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I have custom hardware with a handset device that Android doesnt have any default values or priorities for. I have it listed as an input and output device but i need to be able to set the device on the AudioTrack.

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve my issue I had to download the source code for Exoplayer and expose a way to set the hardware to the track:

DefaultAudioSink.Java

```
private AudioTrack initializeAudioTrack() throws InitializationException {
AudioTrack audioTrack;
if (Util.SDK_INT >= 21) {
  audioTrack = createAudioTrackV21();
  if (audioAttributes.device != null && Util.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    audioTrack.setPreferredDevice(audioAttributes.device);
  }
}
```

The inner if statement was added in above code.

AudioAttributes.Java

```
public Builder setPreferredDevice(AudioDeviceInfo device) {
  this.playbackDevice = device;
  return this;
}

public AudioAttributes build() {
  return new AudioAttributes(contentType, flags, usage, playbackDevice);
}
```

this added a public builder element to allow setting of a preferred device on the AudioAttributes.

```
public AudioDeviceInfo device;
private @Nullable android.media.AudioAttributes audioAttributesV21;
private android.media.AudioAttributes audioAttributesV21;

private AudioAttributes(@C.AudioContentType int contentType, @C.AudioFlags int flags,
  @C.AudioUsage int usage) {
  @C.AudioUsage int usage, AudioDeviceInfo device) {
    this.contentType = contentType;
    this.flags = flags;
    this.usage = usage;
    this.device = device;
}
```

Added variable for AudioDeviceInfo to AudioAttributes constructor.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
if (this == obj) {
  return true;
}
if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
  return false;
}
AudioAttributes other = (AudioAttributes) obj;
return this.contentType == other.contentType && this.flags == other.flags
    && this.usage == other.usage && this.device == other.device;
}
```

added a source formatting check to equals override for the device: && this.device == other.device

This allowed me to compile the project and added as a library as normal but with the addition of being able to set the device i wanted as part of the builder. The bonus was it also works dynamically. Im sure the same could also be achieved with Media
Player

Comment: Glad to hear it helped ^^

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to play two audios on different devices simultaneously ?